# How do Gradient-boosted trees cope with new categories after training?

Tags: boosting, many-categories

I'm looking at using a Gradient-boosted tree model to predict categories for a dataset.  The data has has multiple categorical variables which have high cardinality.  I've converted the dataset into one-hot encoded format ready for training.

However, once the dataset it trained, it's likely that the incoming production data will have novel categories.  Will this invalidate the model? What's the best way to deal with that?

Comment: Similar Q:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/248438/label-encoding-for-high-cardinality-features-in-boosted-decision-trees-what-to?rq=1